# How can i fill a array on state?

Tags: reactjs

Im using onError method to call this function:

And I need to set on state every time when onError method is executed.

```
brokenMobImg(e){
    var image = e.target
    image.parentNode.removeChild(image);
    this.setState({broken: e.target.src})
    console.log('IMGS:', this.state.broken);
    }
```

Comment: Seems ok. What is the problem? Where is the array you mention in the title?

Comment: I'm assuming you need to maintain a list of such src. so you will have to append to the existing list: `this.setState({broken: this.state.broken.concat(e.target.src) });` Note, not using `.push` as it mutates array

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your errors as an array in state first then update the array with your new error rather than just replacing your broken variable each time. Here is a codesandbox example that does something similar to what you are wanting to do: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-haze-cshem?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

```
Current:

brokenMobImg(e){
    var image = e.target
    image.parentNode.removeChild(image);
    this.setState({broken: e.target.src})
    console.log('IMGS:', this.state.broken);
    }

Solution:

constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state ={
    broken:[]
   }
}

brokenMobImg(e){
    var image = e.target;
    var brokenInState = this.state.broken;
    image.parentNode.removeChild(image);
    brokenInState.push(e.target.src);
    this.setState({broken: brokenInState},()=>{
       console.log('IMGS:', this.state.broken);
    });
}
```